# What is transferred and/or unlocked when importing saved data from Project Diva F into Project Diva F 2nd?

Tags: project-diva-f, project-diva-f-2nd

What is transferred and/or unlocked when importing saved data from Project Diva F into Project Diva F 2nd?

I saw multiple sites listing different content that is transferred and/or unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Modules and customization items are imported onto f 2nd. From page 9 of the Vita digital manual:

[image]